# TypeError: must be str, not dict in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, firebase

I am following [this tutorial](http://adataanalyst.com/machine-learning/apriori-algorithm-python-3-0/) and trying to extract certain value out to be inserted into Firebase.

How can I actually group certain type together, remove duplicates and insert into Firebase with desired structure? Like for example:

```
household cleaning
    kitchen appliance: conf
    air freshener: conf
    laundry & ironing needs: conf
kitchen appliance
    household cleaning: conf
    ...
```

Because I intended to do something like, for each type, I get the associated type together with its conf and insert into Firebase. But as of now I not sure how can I achieve it. What I have tried so far is:

```
result = list()
calcConf()
    result.append((freqSet-conseq, conseq, conf))
for freqSet in result:
    for item in freqSet:
        print(item)
```

It did split out each associated type as such:

```
set({'household cleaning'})
set({'kitchen appliance'})
0.5087719298245614
set({'kitchen appliance'})
set({'household cleaning'})
0.4172661870503597
set({'household cleaning'})
set({'air freshener'})
0.7105263157894738
```

But I not sure how can I proceed further to insert into the desired structure into Firebase. Previously I was doing in JavaScript with object array but I not sure if it is applicable in Python as well. Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I tried with object array:

```
class parts:
    def __init__(self, s1, s1, s3):
        self.s1= s1
        self.s2= s2
        self.s3= s3
```

Then, I populated the result list as such:

```
result.append(parts(freqSet, conseq, conf))
```

When I tried to insert into firebase:

```
for t in result:
    fstr= t.freqSet.strip('set({})')
    cstr= t.conseq.strip('set({})')
    print(fstr, cstr, t.conf)

    firebase.patch('/test/' + fstr+ {cstr: t.conf})
```

I am getting this error message:

```
 firebase.patch('/marketBasketAnalysis/' + fstr + {cstr: t.conf})
TypeError: must be str, not dict
```

Comment: Take a look at pandas, it's good for managing datasets and dealing with things like grouping related items.

Comment: @Barmar I tried to declare an object array as per edited portion but I am getting some error message. Do you mind to take a look?

Comment: Oh shit sorry my bad. I am used to the object array in JavaScript. It should be t.freqSet instead and it's working now. Now I am left with removing the duplicate and the 'frozenset' wording

Comment: @Barmar Hey I have encounter another error when trying to insert into Firebase. Do you have any ideas why is it so?

Comment: What are you expecting `+ {conseqStr: t.conf}` to do? You can't concatenate a dictionary to a string.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry my bad! I realized the problem also. It's now solved. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the edited portion by:

```
firebase.patch('/test/' + fstr , {cstr: t.conf})
```